# mongodb folder size is very big

Tags: debian, mongodb, debian-jessie

I installed a mongodb on a Debian Jessie. After some inserts (<100) I checked the size of the folder /var/lib/mongodb/ and the content of the folder is 3.3 GB high.

Is this normal?

The hard disk size is 20GB and 50% is free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that is normal. Mongodb pre-allocates blocks of data for writes to happen. This allows it to handle more write operations without taxing your disk. Take a look at the following for more information

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/faq/storage/#faq-disk-size